# Silverlight.FX and SL4

Tags: silverlight

Does anybody know if Silverlight.FX is compatible with Silverlight 4?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [web page](http://projects.nikhilk.net/SilverlightFX) there are only versions for Silverlight 2 and Silverlight 3.5. The latest release is dated 24 March 2010 which predates the full release of Silverlight 4.

However, if you have the source it might not be too difficult to get it to compile in Silverlight 4. Recently I had to convert an SL 3 application to SL 4 and it was largely a mechanical process of updating some references and namespaces. The 99% of the code "just worked" once I got it to compile.